# Unable to format date column read from excel to system date format

Tags: r

I read a file from excel using read.table method in R. I want  to format the DATE column from m/d/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd format.

The class of DATE column is character, so converted it to DATE using
as.Date(sp500$Date).

Data:

```
> head(sp500)
       Date Adj.Close
1  7/1/2019   2964.33
2 6/28/2019   2941.76
3 6/27/2019   2924.92
4 6/26/2019   2913.78
5 6/25/2019   2917.38
6 6/24/2019   2945.35

sp500$Date <- as.Date(sp500$Date, format='%m/%d/%y')
```

Output:

```
> head(sp500)
        Date Adj.Close
1 2020-07-01   2964.33
2 2020-06-28   2941.76
3 2020-06-27   2924.92
4 2020-06-26   2913.78
5 2020-06-25   2917.38
6 2020-06-24   2945.35
```

In the output I expected date to be "2019-07-01" but  the actual output is "2020-07-01"

How to get the expected DATE format in R?

Comment: %y is two digit year, needs %Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic issue, there is a difference between `%y` and `%Y` - when using `%y` it reads the first two characters and then stops, see the difference by running this:

```
X <- "07/07/2019"
as.Date(X, "%d/%m/%Y") # four-digit year
as.Date(X, "%d/%m/%y") # two-digit year
```

Answer (score 0):

Try lubridate, it detects the format

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(sp500$Date) #means day then month then year
```